# Sharepoint 2013 SearchBoxEx scopes not loading properly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, scopes, search-box, sharepoint-branding

I need to brand the sharepoint search box to allow scopes. When using the default SearchBoxScriptWebPart, the scopes do show as required. However I need the scopes to show as text besides the dropdown arrow (the default SearchBoxScriptWebPart only shows an arrow which when clicked shows the dropdown with all the scopes). Then I tried using the SearchBoxEx which seems to be perfect for the job. However for some reason it is not loading the scopes I specified in the Site Settings > Search Settings. 
Any ideas what I may be doing wrong for the SearchBoxEx?

This is the code I am using in the masterpage:

```
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server" GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" GoImageUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" DropDownMode="ShowDD_NoContextual" QueryPromptString="Start typing here" UseSiteDefaults="true" />
```

Note that I tried every possible combination of DropDownMode but still to no avail.
Thanks